# Spring boot scheduled tasks shutdown by itself

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a spring boot scheduled task, as mentioned in the [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/). When I run the application it is just starting and stopping, and I don't get to see the output as mentioned in the guides. Below the logs

```
2015-10-19 17:54:14.366  INFO 4512 --- [lication.main()] o.litmos.workday.batch.app.Application   : Starting Application on RohitNagesh-PC with PID 1118
2015-10-19 17:54:14.418  INFO 4512 --- [lication.main()] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@84cebe: startup date [Mon Oct 19 17:54:14 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-10-19 17:54:14.790  INFO 4512 --- [lication.main()] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
2015-10-19 17:54:15.088  INFO 4512 --- [lication.main()] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3770f0ed] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-19 17:54:15.258  INFO 4512 --- [lication.main()] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-10-19 17:54:15.279  INFO 4512 --- [lication.main()] o.litmos.workday.batch.app.Application   : Started Application in 1.184 seconds (JVM running for 5.503)
2015-10-19 17:54:15.366  INFO 4512 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@84cebe: startup date [Mon Oct 19 17:54:14 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-10-19 17:54:15.367  INFO 4512 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

How can make the task to run endless until I stop it?

Adding my code below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ImportResource("applicationContext.xml")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Batch Started");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}


@Component
public class SampleJob {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
         System.out.println("The time is now " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Batch dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: Have you done exactly as in the guide or more or less followed the guide... Looks to me as if you don't have `@EnableScheduling`on your main class.

Comment: I have added my current code

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in the file applicationContext.xml?? In the link, that you provided, there is no @ImportResource, so it seems that you have bad configuration on Spring xml.
If you want to fix it, I would rather go to this link:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: The context file was containing an empty beans tag. I have removed this and tried, but keeps getting the same result.